# Which Xcode version should I download for macOS High Sierra 10.13.6?

Tags: macbook-pro, xcode, macos-highsierra

Which Xcode version should I download for macOS High Sierra 10.13.6?

Note that I downloaded Xcode 10.2, but it informed me that it requires macOS 10.14.3 or later.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596733/is-it-possible-to-install-xcode-10-2-on-high-sierra-10-13-6 but note that from April 2020 all submissions must be from Xcode 11.

Comment: Xcode 11 inform me that it requires Mac OS 10.14.3 or later. -@Tetsujin

Answer (score 8):

You can use Xcode 10.1 the max auto supported version for Mac High sierra 10.13.6

use the following link : https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip

it requires Apple ID as well to download the xcode.

reference link for all Xcode versions and max supported os
https://xcodereleases.com/

Comment: Could you add a source for that?

Comment: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip

Comment: use your Apple ID to download the .xip file

Comment: What I was trying to hint at is could you [edit] your answer to include the documentation source saying that the 10.1 is the highest version available? Please see [answer].